# Problem with Deploy page using tailwind CSS to GitHub Pages

Tags: github, github-pages, github-pages-deploy-action

I created a basic project with tailwind CSS, I can upload it to GitHub, but I don't know how to expose it to GitHub pages as .github.io/tailwind-project/
I am getting the contents of the README.md file instead of the index.html

How to edit the deploy.yml file please?

I have the following project structure in VS Code
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CmWio.jpg)

and subsequently on GitHub
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Dq1O.jpg)

Thank your help

Set the deploy.yml file using GitHub Actions

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.